# React.js "global" component that can be created multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't get my head wrapped around this.

The problem: let's say there's an app and there can be some sort of notifications/dialogs/etc that i want to create from my code.

I can have "global" component and manage it, but it would limit me to only one notification at a time, this will not fit.

```
render() {
  <App>
    // Some components...
    <Notification />
  </App>
}
```

Or i can manage multiple notifications by the component `Notification` itself. But state management will not be clear.

The other problem if i have some sort of user confirmation from that component (if it's a confirmation dialog instead of simple notification) this will not be very convinient to handle with this solution.

The other solution is to render a component manually. Something like:

```
notify(props) {
  const wrapper = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  const component = ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Notification, props), wrapper)
  //...
  // return Promise or component itself
}
```

So i would call as:

```
notify({message: '...'})
  .then(...)
```

or:

```
notify({message: '...', onConfirm: ...})
```

This solution seems hacky, i would like to let React handle rendering, and i have an additional needless `div`. Also, if React API changes, my code breaks.

**What is the best practice for this scenario? Maybe i'm missing something completely different?**

Comment: Sorry but your question seems to be unclear.

Comment: What kind of state management do you use? This kind of problem is why tools such as Redux was invented. Components can pass data to a shared data store without knowing about the other components that uses that data. Decoupling component logic makes larger apps much more maintainable.

Comment: @HåkenLid Would you need to introduce redux for this? Seems like React Context would work perfectly here.

Comment: There's no state management yet. But it doesn't seem that this problem is solved with state management (or i just don't understand a good way). So, for example, user tried to delete some data related to the component, i should ask a confirmation. So i pass pending "deletion request" to state, then some other component gets it, manages 'ok' button and passes resolved "deletion request" and initial component get this state and renders correctly? Doesn't seem very clear atm to me.

Comment: @CameronDowner this is a very pertinent comment, a lot of people, me included, will not think of Context API by default and I think there's a lot of cases where redux workflow can be replaced by a simple Context API usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this.

You create a React context at a high level in your application and then associate a values to it. This should allow components to create / interact with notifications.

```
export const NotificationContext = React.createContext({
  notifications: [],
  createNotification: () => {}
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      notifications: []
    };

    this.createNotification = this.createNotification.bind(this);
  }

  createNotification(body) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      notifications: [body, ...prevState.notifications]
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { notifications } = this.state;

    const contextValue = {
      notifications,
      createNotification: this.createNotification
    };
    return (
      <NotificationContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <NotificationButton />
        {notifications.map(notification => (
          <Notification body={notification} />
        ))}
      </NotificationContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The notifications are stored in an array to allow multiple at a time. Currently, this implementation will never delete them but this functionality can be added.

To create a notification, you will use the corresponding context consumer from within the App. I have added a simple implementation here for demonstration purposes.

```
import { NotificationContext } from "./App.jsx";

const NotificationButton = () => (
  <NotificationContext.Consumer>
    {({ notifications, createNotification }) => (
      <button onClick={() => createNotification(notifications.length)}>
        Add Notification
      </button>
    )}
  </NotificationContext.Consumer>
);
```

[You can view the working example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooqkp45xz)

Comment: This is actually great for simple notifications. But what if i want user input? Do i need to go Redux?

Comment: @UnstableFractal No, you wouldn't need Redux. You would just have to pass in the user input to the `createNotification` function.

Comment: I meant the case when it's a modal dialog with confirmation insted of notification. When i'm waiting for user input to, for example, send fetch request.

Comment: I think it depends on the nature of the requests. If you need the state of or response from the request in another component, I would introduce Redux at that point.