# How to create a global notification?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a basic View component in React that will contain an iOS style banner notification across every view and some children. I want to be able to toggle the notification component from anywhere, in any view.

For example I might click a button on a form, and then show a warning notification.

```
<View>
 <Notification type="success" text="Account updated!" >
 // other children components here
 // including a button to change the state of the notification
</View>
```

I need to have a method – showNotification() in the View component that can control the state of the Notification, update the text and so on.

I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this. I've been able to add a button inside  that shows the notification, but it doesn't work for buttons outside of the  component.

What is the best approach for doing this?

I've tried creating a View class that extends React.Component and has a showNotification() method, along with a state passed to the  component.

Then I create a new view that extends my custom View class and called super.showNotification()

This calls the function in the parent class and updates the state, but doesn't seem to pass the state to the  component prop.

Comment: Are you wanting to have a single <Notification /> Element that shows in any window but can be controlled within elements?

Comment: Yes – exactly this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to head out for a couple of hours, but I would suggest looking at using the React Context API with the new React Hooks. You can create something called a global state (Used to be you would use something called Redux, or similar) that you can access in any of your components. From this you can set a state for visibility or your <Notification /> element, but also it means you could create the element at a higher level (say App.js) and control it from any component you want. I will try to create a demo later for you if no one has provided one by then!

Comment: It's also very useful to learn the new Hooks and Context API's, incredibly powerful! I'd also advise against using Inheritance with components. They should be a little more self contained than that, Compose components with other components is the best way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do some reading on the context API now :-)

Comment: Little self promotion, but I've answered a question like this before. It could be updated with hooks as @TristanTrainer suggested though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111433/react-js-global-component-that-can-be-created-multiple-times/52115442#52115442

Comment: Amazing, thank you @CameronDowner :-)